# Django Select2 widget load more results request almost crashes browsers

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery-select2

I've implemented a Select2 widget in a django form which pulls in initial results without a problem, but then when you scroll through & it attempts to load more results, the entire page stops responding, Safari on mobile crashes, and if you leave it long enough will return a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

My form field is setup like so;

```
class MySelect2Field(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    search_fields = ['name__icontains']
    max_results = 10
    queryset = Clubs.objects


class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    club_name = MySelect2Field(
        label="Club name",
        widget=AutoHeavySelect2Widget(
            select2_options={
                'minimumInputLength': 3,
                'width': '100%'
            }
        ),
        required=False,
    )
```

Is there a problem with this implementation, because I've essentially followed the [docs](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_started.html) to get to where I am.

Is there anything you can add to the setup to improve the reliability of the Ajax requests?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [djang0-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2)?